# Why do I need braces in Haskell for 'neg square 4.2'?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently learning Haskell with [99 questions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions) and I have seen `.` in one solution. It seems to be usual function composition as known in math:

```
f ∘ g
```

I wanted to make sure that I've understood it correctly and created this example:

```
square x = x*x
neg x = (-1)*x

main = do
    -- let result = neg (square 4.1) -- works
    -- let result = square (neg 4.2) -- works
    -- let result = neg $ square 4.3 -- works
    let result = neg square 4.4 -- doesn't work
    -- let result = neg . square 4.5 -- doesn't work
    -- let result = neg . square $ 4.6 -- works
    -- let result = neg square $ 4.7 -- does not work

    print result
```

Sadly, only the first three lines work (at least they work as expected).

Why do I need braces in the lower two cases? I thought that you would not need them, becasue I thought that with the dot, `neg` gets `square` as input. So it is still a function and looks like

```
(-1)*x*(-1)*x
```

then 4.4 is put in there for `x` which should be fine.

I thought that without the dot, Haskell first applicates `square` to 4.5 and then `neg` is applied to the result.

But apparently there is a problem. What is the problem in the lower two cases?

Comment: Because of precedence specified with `infixr` for `.`, `$` (and implied for function application), `neg . square 4.5 == (.) (neg) (square 4.5)`, `neg . square $ 4.6 == ($) ((.) (neg) (square)) (4.6)`, and `neg square $ 4.7 == ($) (neg (square)) (4.7)`

Answer (score 6):

Function application () has the highest precedence of all the operators in Haskell, so

`neg . square 4.5` means `neg . (square 4.5)`, which doesn't make sense because `(square 4.5)` is a number, not a function, so you can't compose it with `neg`.

and `neg square $ 4.7` means `(neg square) $ 4.7`, but `square` is a function not a number, so you can't `neg` it.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, function application is left associative so `a b c d` means `((a b) c) d)`.

You can read more about this at : http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

The type of `neg` is

```
neg:: Num a => a -> a
```

You are attempting to apply two arguments to neg when it only takes one.
`(.)` is function composition, not concatenation.

`let result = neg . square 4.5` should be `let result = neg . square $ 4.5`

In the case of `neg . square` you are composing two functions.

The type of `(.)`is `(b -> c) -> (a -> c) -> a -> c`
So when you compose it with `neg` and `square` it becomes `neg . square :: Num c => c -> c` and now takes one argument. If you attempt to apply `42` to `neg . square` immediately, the application of `4.4` applied to `square` will take precedence over the composition of `neg`and `square` applied to `4.4` (since function application is left-associative) and will produce a type error.